# Differentiations between types of love in languages?

Tags: list-of-languages

Are there any languages with distinctions between romantic, Platonic, familial, etc. love?  The closest I know of is "te quiero" doesn't have the same connotations as "te amo" in Spanish.

Comment: [Ancient Greek certainly did](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_words_for_love) (and Modern Greek to some extent has inherited that).

Comment: Many languages have that differentiation, e.g. Greek, Spanish, Tamil, Sanskrit, American Sign Language, Arabic, Japanese. [This article](https://www.fluentin3months.com/words-for-love/) lists the words for ‘love’ in the abovementioned languages together with their English translations and explanations.